# Document Library Share QCB not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, share

I am using SharePoint 2016 and a custom masterpage. However, my Share button on QCB is not working. Only share button. The rest works perfectly fine. There are no errors when i clicked the button. No network is firing though.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing about your customizations to your masterpage, it's not possible to tell the exact reason why this is happening. I'd suggest to have a look at your browser's console (click <kbd>F12</kbd> > Console-tab) and look for any JavaScript-errors or any other errors. If none found, look at the DOM elements of the Share-button by again inspecting through the browser's Developer Tools. If some of the elements are affected by CSS-changes, you can try to revert/overwriting those changes while still using the Developer Tools.

If no customizations, errors, or other signs are found by inspecting the page, you need to start to dig through your done customizations.